# formmethod.post vs formmethod.get in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm working on a cascading dropdownlist in mvc3, when i used formmethod.post im able to select a value in dropdownlsi1 and based on the that selection im able to get values in dropdownlist2 and after selecting an item in dropdownlist2 , im getting a button which on clicking will give the user a message u have selected X and Y.....this is fine and i have no issue with it

but when i used formmethod.get, im able to get the 1st dropdownlist and based on the selection in the 1st dropdownlist im able to get 2nd dropdownlist nd items in the 2nd dropdownlist, after the selection in the 2nd dropdownlist , i got a button , but after clicking the button, again im seeing the same page when i get when i load the page i.e  only the 1t dropdownlist..

In what scenario we should use formmethod.post and formmethod.get?

Comment: Do you know the difference between GET and POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `formmethod.get` when you make http get request and `formmethod.post` when you make http post request it is methods of parameters. It seems to me your solution is to pass previous selected values of dropdown lists into the view and initialize helpers with selected values to render them properly.

It **could be done** with **both** request types.

Answer (score 1):

You have two actions:

- [HttpGet]
- [HttpPost]

In first action you load page, if you use `Post` method, then you send `Post` data to second action. If you use `Get` method you just reload `form action`, it also send data, but they are included in url, like this `site.com?param=1&test=2`.

[GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Get_vs_Post)